# Decrypting CryptoJS AES data (with passphrase) in Forge.js

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

So I have a piece of code which encrypts a string with a passphrase. It uses the CryptoJS AES encrypt function (`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`) and looks like this...

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, password).toString();
```

Going forward, I don't want to be using CryptoJS, as it's officially deprecated/not maintained, and I would instead like to use Forge.js. I've attempted to read through the Forge.js docs on GitHub to find a solution, but haven't been able to find anything which uses passphrases instead of manually creating the key & IV.

I've taken a look at the CryptoJS archive at https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/ and it seems that if the `encrypt` function is passed a string as the second argument (key) it's used as a passphrase to derive a key and IV. But it doesn't detail how it does this.

It seems that base64 decoding the result gives a string that starts with `Salted__` then a comma and then the encrypted blob of binary text, and I'm unsure even how I would pass the "salt" through to Forge.

How would I go about decrypting this blob of data using Forge.js only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CryptoJS supports OpenSSL's EVP_BytesToKey function, which derives a key and IV from a freshly generated salt and password with one round of MD5. There is an example on the [forge documentation page](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge):

> Using forge in node.js to match openssl's "enc" command line tool
>   (**Note:** OpenSSL "enc" uses a non-standard file format with a custom key
>   derivation function and a fixed iteration count of 1, which some
>   consider less secure than alternatives such as OpenPGP/GnuPG):
>
> ```
> var forge = require('node-forge');
> var fs = require('fs');
>
> // openssl enc -des3 -in input.txt -out input.enc
> function encrypt(password) {
>   var input = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', {encoding: 'binary'});
>
>   // 3DES key and IV sizes
>   var keySize = 24;
>   var ivSize = 8;
>
>   // get derived bytes
>   // Notes:
>   // 1. If using an alternative hash (eg: "-md sha1") pass
>   //   "forge.md.sha1.create()" as the final parameter.
>   // 2. If using "-nosalt", set salt to null.
>   var salt = forge.random.getBytesSync(8);
>   // var md = forge.md.sha1.create(); // "-md sha1"
>   var derivedBytes = forge.pbe.opensslDeriveBytes(
>     password, salt, keySize + ivSize/*, md*/);
>   var buffer = forge.util.createBuffer(derivedBytes);
>   var key = buffer.getBytes(keySize);
>   var iv = buffer.getBytes(ivSize);
>
>   var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('3DES-CBC', key);
>   cipher.start({iv: iv});
>   cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(input, 'binary'));
>   cipher.finish();
>
>   var output = forge.util.createBuffer();
>
>   // if using a salt, prepend this to the output:
>   if(salt !== null) {
>     output.putBytes('Salted__'); // (add to match openssl tool output)
>     output.putBytes(salt);
>   }
>   output.putBuffer(cipher.output);
>
>   fs.writeFileSync('input.enc', output.getBytes(), {encoding: 'binary'});
> }
>
> // openssl enc -d -des3 -in input.enc -out input.dec.txt
> function decrypt(password) {
>   var input = fs.readFileSync('input.enc', {encoding: 'binary'});
>
>   // parse salt from input
>   input = forge.util.createBuffer(input, 'binary');
>   // skip "Salted__" (if known to be present)
>   input.getBytes('Salted__'.length);
>   // read 8-byte salt
>   var salt = input.getBytes(8);
>
>   // Note: if using "-nosalt", skip above parsing and use
>   // var salt = null;
>
>   // 3DES key and IV sizes
>   var keySize = 24;
>   var ivSize = 8;
>
>   var derivedBytes = forge.pbe.opensslDeriveBytes(
>     password, salt, keySize + ivSize);
>   var buffer = forge.util.createBuffer(derivedBytes);
>   var key = buffer.getBytes(keySize);
>   var iv = buffer.getBytes(ivSize);
>
>   var decipher = forge.cipher.createDecipher('3DES-CBC', key);
>   decipher.start({iv: iv});
>   decipher.update(input);
>   var result = decipher.finish(); // check 'result' for true/false
>
>   fs.writeFileSync(
>     'input.dec.txt', decipher.output.getBytes(), {encoding: 'binary'});
> }
> ```

This example is shown for Triple DES, but it works in the same way for AES. You just have to change the `ivSize` to 16.

Comment: I appreciate it, this is very much the answer to my question. I overlooked being able to reuse the cited 3DES example with AES.

Comment: I realise that I didn't reply back after I'd tried your suggestion. Maybe I'm missing something, however simply changing `3DES` to `AES` and `8` to `16` for the `ivSize` does not yield the same results. I have tried to hunt down what the issue may be, as forge says that it was successful, but the output is completely different - so I wonder whether it is an encoding related issue? Not too sure.

Comment: Forge outputs the following string...

`1pÍ0¿UÚ@G4WtCÕ5¸«ñZ¿}Á6©_Í¬iñýü¾¸iÔú®ð5ÕÆÉP¹ú)&nQOW»AMØ¨3{~5=O!¼=W²Ò? [...]`

Where as cryptojs outputs the following...

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAqSFulewpMjRBLhiiorbvWleD5I [...]`

I would love to mark this as the correct comment, but with the snippet above right now, I wouldn't want anybody else to come across this and have the same issue.

Comment: I found out why I was getting the issue I noted above - the `input` was base64 encoded, so I ran it through `atob(input)` before it's turned into a buffer. Thanks Artjom!